# Can we make tabs inside a Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, tabs, slidingdrawer

Can we make tabs inside a drawer with android, and is it the same way to do it normally ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we make tabs inside a drawer with android

I would guess so. I have not tried it, but I have not run into problems putting anything else in a `SlidingDrawer`.

That being said, it would be an awfully strange UI.

Moreover, tabs and sliding drawers in general will not be in common use in Honeycomb, with developers instead using multiple fragments that animate on and off the screen. Hence, I would recommend that you not pursue tabs-in-a-sliding-drawer, but instead consider how you will use Android 3.0, and hope that Google comes out with the fragments support for previous versions of Android.

Comment: but the common android version used will be for smartphone, something like froyo or gingerbread. But i would like to see what i can do with Honeycomb.